# makefile compling - make: Nothing to be done for 'all'

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, fortran

I have a makefile and while attempting to compile it with `make -f Makefile.linux` it's giving the error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'
```

I've looked around and haven't found a solution to this. Some others have had a similar problem before but their solutions do not seem to work for me.
Here's my code:

```
FCOMPL=/usr/bin/g77 -m32
FCOM90=gfortran -m32
FFLAGC=-u -Wall -ff2c -fPIC -O

BINDIR=/ami/bin/linux-x86
OLDBIN=/ami/bin/linux-x86/old
LIBDIR=/ami/lib/linux-x86
X11LIB=/usr/X11R6/lib
BLDDIR=./

LIBS=-L/mrao/lib -lutil -lio -lch -lpgplot -L$(X11LIB) -lX11

SOURCE_FILES=./make_sources

include $(SOURCE_FILES)

.SUFFIXES : .f90

.f.o:
    $(FCOMPL) -c $(FFLAGC) $<

.f90.o:
    $(FCOM90) -c $(FFLAGC) $<

#all:profile

libprofile.a : $(OBJECTS)
    ar ru libprofile.a $(OBJECTS)

profile: profile.f90 libprofile.a 
    $(FCOM90) $(FFLAGC) -o profile.linux profile.f90 \
        -L$(BLDDIR) -lprofile \
        -L$(LIBDIR) -lsla -lnag77 -lcfitsio $(LIBS)
    ln -s profile.linux profile
    chmod g+w *.o *.mod *.a profile.linux

install: profile
    mv $(BINDIR)/profile $(OLDBIN)/profile
    cp -p profile.linux $(BINDIR)/profile
    chmod g+w $(BINDIR)/profile

previous:
    mv $(OLDBIN)/profile $(BINDIR)/profile

clean:  
    rm profile.linux profile *.o *.mod *.a
```

Comment: From your question it is unclear if you ran the command before or not. In you did nothing has been changed regarding the dependencies and thus nothing has to be (re-) build so make just tells you this.

Comment: I recommend you brush up on the basics of how `make` works.

Comment: Why do you believe it should do some compiling? Did you change some source file?

Comment: "Nothing to be done" means all the targets are already up to date. Unless there is a bug in the Makefile, this is not a problem at all. Make is doing its job, making sure you don't recompile things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

This can be fixed by typing:

`make clean -f Makefile.linux`

followed by

`make -f Makefile.linux`

Comment: This would only remove all (generated) files and with the next make invocation the dependencies were not satisfied so make has to start some build commands.

Comment: Well, it’s recompiled the code and this currently works. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: This is seriously what you learned? In order to force a make with all dependencies complete, run `make clean`?